# Facebook Graph API call to get the profile nickname

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've set up a nickname of my facebook profile following the next steps:

1. Click on your facebook profile
2. Click on "About" menu option
3. From the left menu click on "Details about you"
4. Click " + Add a nickname, a birth name..." from "OTHER NAMES"
5. From drop down list select "Nickname"
6. Fill into input field with your nickname

My question is:

Which is the Graph API call to recover the nickname above set it up?

This Graph API call: "me/?fields=nickname", is not working